# How to get current location through Google API using FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, google-api

I want to know my current location through Google API. In the code shown below i have used `FusedLocationApi` which is deprecated and instead i should use `FusedLocationProviderClient` which i dont know how to use also i have read Android official document but didnt get to the point. Below is my `AndroidManifest.xml` and `MainActivity.java` file:

Also i have added dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hp.location2">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.hp.location2;

import android.Manifest;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private static final String TAG = "MyApps-Location2";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private TextView mLatitudeText;
private TextView mLongitudeText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLatitudeText = findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);
    mLongitudeText = findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient Connected");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient DisConnected");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
}
}
```

It would be great if i get working code.

Thank You

Comment: You are using a deprecated api.. You should read and implement this: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

Answer (score 1):

There two methods of FusedLocationProviderClient which would help you getting the current location. 
1. Through LocationCallBack method, you would get your location.
2. In OnConnected method stting the loactionCallBAcks and fusedLocationClient will be updated with the location.

I have revised your code, please check the code below.

```
import android.Manifest;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    private static final String TAG = "MyApps-Location2";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private TextView mLatitudeText;
    private TextView mLongitudeText;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            //checkPermissions();
        }

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);


        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

                    Log.d("StackProblem",latLng+"");


                    mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);

                }
            };
        };


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient Connected");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient DisConnected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {



        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,mLocationCallback,null);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
    }
}
```

Where I have written **Log.d("StackProblem",latLng+"");**  you are getting Latitude and Longitude, just try methods like latlng.getLatitude and latLng.getLongitude.

Hope that Helps.

Comment: @user9303364  it is a local variable in onLocationResult   Method

Comment: In my case when i run, it's showing same error which i previously mentioned. May be you have used maps API Classes `import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;` I am not sure

Comment: @user9303364 Try adding this dependency implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0"

Comment: @user9303364 Also if you are just in want of latitude and longitutde that you'll get from the onLocationResult method. In the constructor of that method you are getting a location object, try using location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude(), you'll surely get the double value in return.

Comment: @user9303364 it helped or not??